# OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer while multiplying a string with a large int

Tags: python-3.x, string, overflow

`
k = int(input())

string = 'codeforce'

real = string + k*'s'

print(real)`

I'm trying to multiply a string 's' with a int 10^16.

But it gives me OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

How can I get rid of it?[The image shows all the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1maY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should add the code in your question and not add image file to show your code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The result of multplying a string by an integer *k* is that string repeated *k* times (whichever order the multiplication is).  For example:

```
>>> 3 * "s"
'sss'

>>> "s" * 3
'sss'
```

In this case, you have requested a string of length 10^16.  This would require 10 petabytes of virtual address space to store.  Even if your python implementation in principle allowed you to create an object of that size, it is extremely unlikely that your machine's physical hardware limitations would allow it (even allowing for the use of swap space).

The exact maximum is likely to be implementation-dependent.  For example, in python running on x86_64 Linux, an `OverflowError` is raised where *k* is 2^63 or more, i.e. when the length cannot be stored in a 64-bit `signed long`.  For numbers less than that but where memory would nonetheless be exhausted, a `MemoryError` is raised instead.

In your Python implementation, the cutoff seems to be lower than 2^63 (which is approximately `9e18`).  It is therefore possible that a 32-bit `signed int` is being used as an "index-size integer", which would imply a maximum string length of 2GB.  If that is the case, then this is within the amount of physical memory which is actually plausible on your system, in which case it is possible that there is a limit which actually matters.  In that case, you might need to redesign any code in order to reduce the length of the strings used.